# Django site - RSS feed - keep getting attribute error for description

Tags: python, django, rss

I'm trying to put a very simple RSS feed on my django blog and have been trying all day to get it to work but keep getting various errors. I am now getting an Attribute error because "posts object has no attribute 'description'"

There must be something very simple that I am missing here because I cannot get even the most basic RSS feed to work. I have also included my model at the bottom because I am wondering if I need to have a 'description' field in my model in order to use RSS?

```
class RSSFeed(Feed):
title = "title"
link = "/"
description = "something"

def items(self):
    return posts.objects.all()

def item_description(self, item):
    return item.description


class posts(models.Model):
author = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
title = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
bodytext = models.TextField()
timestamp = models.DateTimeField()
slug = models.SlugField(max_length = 255)


def get_absolute_url(self):
    return ('blog.views.home', None, {'slug': self.slug})
```

Comment: Well clearly your posts does not have a description as one of the attributes, you have author,title,bodytext etc not description ???

Comment: try with `def item_description(self):`

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to feed your posts, then in this method, most certainly `item` is of type `posts`:

```
def item_description(self, item):
    return item.description
```

Hence the error, because your post doesn't have any description.

Try a quick fix like this:

```
class posts(models.Model):
    author = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    bodytext = models.TextField()
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField()
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length = 255)


    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return ('blog.views.home', None, {'slug': self.slug})

    @property
    def description(self):
        return 'post description'
```

See if it worked, if it does, then add the proper field to your models for a description to posts.

Also watch your indentation. In your question it is a mess. I guess you missed up with the `Markdown` editor but just in case it's worth to mention.

Hope this helps!